# Auto Assign x No of Records against X No of People depending on Value of a Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on automating handling of the assignment of large set of records, dividing it equally to a the number of people based on the record name.

There is no fixed count of how many records there will be everyday and the number of people keeps on changing also from time to time hence will be updating the list of people from time to time.

The Records are in Tab Records and column A. Under the same tab, the Assigned To column is in column B. The People are in People Tab under column A.

I need a macro that will count the number of records that are marked as "xyz" and divide them by the number of people then use that number to assign each records equally and input the person's name under column B on the records tab. Then  when the record is marked as "abc" no allocation should be done, hence, column B should be left as blank.

If done manually, it should look like as below.

However, I couldn't figure out how to make it skip all the abcs and assign only the xyz.

Appreciate your help on this please. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
Dim a
With Sheets("People")
    a = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
End With
With Sheets("Records")
    With .Range("a2", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Columns("b")
        If .Rows.Count <= UBound(a, 1) Then
            .Value = a
        Else
            .Resize(UBound(a, 1)).Value = a
            .Resize(UBound(a, 1)).AutoFill .Resize(.Rows.Count)
        End If
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you can't divide evenly - for example 12x "xyz" but 5 names. How is that chase gonna be handled?

Comment: Good question. That didn't even cross my mind. But if that happens, I'll add the balance to the last person in my list. Thanks.

Comment: Could you not make your life a bit easier by sorting by column A?

Comment: Data used here is just my test data, and I've just taken this portion of the report to highlight where I'm stuck at the moment ( part of a huge reporting process with other codes in it). Thanks for asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that every time, the 2 sheets will look exactly like the ones you provided, you can create a macro and paste the following code between i.e. "Sub Assign_names()" and "End Sub". Then run the macro (Alt+F8) and it will do the job!

```
' Count number of names
i = 1

While Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) <> 0

    i = i + 1

Wend
 
' Count number of xyz
j = 1
count_xyz = 0

While Sheet1.Cells(j, 1) <> 0

    If Sheet1.Cells(j, 1) = "xyz" Then
    xyz = xyz + 1
    End If
    j = j + 1

Wend

count_names = i - 2 ' Get number of names
count_xyz = xyz     ' Get number of xyz

xyz_share = Int(count_xyz / count_names) ' Get number of xyz for each name

k = 2
m = 2
cur_xyz_count = 1
cur_name = Sheet2.Cells(2, 1)

' Assign the names to xyz

While Sheet1.Cells(k, 1) <> ""

    cur_name = Sheet2.Cells(m, 1)
    
    If Sheet1.Cells(k, 1) = "xyz" Then ' Add names only to rows with a xyz
        
        cur_xyz_count = cur_xyz_count + 1

        If cur_xyz_count > xyz_share Then ' Check when to change the name
            m = m + 1
            cur_xyz_count = 1
        End If
        
        'Handle the case where count_xyz and count_names can't be divided evenly. Trick to assign remaining xyz to the last name in the list.
        If cur_name = "" Then cur_name = Sheet2.Cells(m - 1, 1)
        Sheet1.Cells(k, 2) = cur_name
                    
    End If
    
    k = k + 1
    
Wend
```

Comment: Many thanks, i updated it to fit my actual report and it worked perfectly! Appreciate it very much.

Comment: I'm glad I helped!

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

The algorithm below assigns the names sequentially, so the `xyz`'s will be distributed as evenly as possible. If you really need to have them assigned in ***batches*** as you show, then I can add to the algorithm to do that, but is that really necessary?

***Original Data***
[image]

***M Code***

```
let

//Change next lines depending on actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Records"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Records", type text}}),

//Note that the Names list was turned into a **Table** named `People`
//Do something similar with your data
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="People"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"Name", type text}}),

    Names = Table.Column(#"Changed Type2","Name"),

//create list of names to combine with the original Records column
    #"Name List" = List.Accumulate(
        #"Changed Type"[Records],
        {},
        (s,c)=> if c = "xyz" 
            then s & 
                {Names{Number.Mod(
                    List.Count(List.RemoveNulls(s)),
                    List.Count(Names)
                    )}} else s & {null }),

//Add the Names column
    #"Add Column" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") & {#"Name List"},
        type table[Record=text, Name=text])
in 
    #"Add Column"
```

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried it, and it also worked but the other solution was more fitting. Appreciate it very much.